# pgi openacc throwing segmentation fault on copyin and copyout

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, openacc

I have narrowed down my problem with the segmentation fault thrown on my code to be something with the line

```
#pragma acc data copyout(result_mat[0:MAT1_X][0:MAT2_Y]), copyin(mat1[0:MAT1_X][0:MAT1_Y],mat2[0:MAT2_X][0:MAT2_Y])
```

in the following code:

```
// https://github.com/wrembish/MatMul_Parallel.git
#include <iostream>

#include <omp.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

// constant variables for the desired size of matrix 1
const size_t MAT1_X = 835;
const size_t MAT1_Y = 835;

// constant variables for the desired size of matrix 2
const size_t MAT2_X = 835;
const size_t MAT2_Y = 835;

int main() 
{
    // take start time of whole program
    auto prog_start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    // seed rand for randomly filling the matrices
    srand(time(NULL));

    // define the matrices to the variables mat1 and mat2
    int mat1[MAT1_X][MAT1_Y];
    int mat2[MAT2_X][MAT2_Y];

    // define the result matrix
    int result_mat[MAT1_X][MAT2_Y];

    // zero result matrix
    #pragma acc loop
    for(int unsigned i = 0; i < MAT1_X; i++)
    {
        for(int unsigned j = 0; j < MAT2_Y; j++)
        {
            result_mat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    // fill in mat1 with random positive integers <= 100
    #pragma acc loop
    for(int unsigned i = 0; i < MAT1_X; i++)
    {
        for(int unsigned j = 0; j < MAT1_Y; j++)
        {
            mat1[i][j] = (rand() % 100) + 1;
        }
    }

    // fill in mat2 with random positive integers <= 100
    #pragma acc loop    
    for(int unsigned i = 0; i < MAT2_X; i++)
    {
        for(int unsigned j = 0; j < MAT2_Y; j++)
        {
            mat2[i][j] = (rand() % 100) + 1;
        }
    }

    // if the matrices can be multiplied, do it
    if(MAT1_Y == MAT2_X)
    {
        //#pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(auto) collapse(3)
        #pragma acc data copyout(result_mat[0:MAT1_X][0:MAT2_Y]), copyin(mat1[0:MAT1_X][0:MAT1_Y],mat2[0:MAT2_X][0:MAT2_Y])
        #pragma kernels
        for(int unsigned i = 0; i < MAT1_X; i++)
        {
            //#pragma acc loop
            for(int unsigned j = 0; j < MAT2_Y; j++)
            {
                //#pragma acc loop seq
                for(int unsigned k = 0; k < MAT1_Y; k++)
                {
                    result_mat[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
                }
            }
        }

    } else
    {
        cout << "the dimensions of the two matrices don't allow multiplication" << endl;
    }

    // take end time of whole program
    auto prog_stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // get the difference in time between program start and finish
    auto prog_duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(prog_stop - prog_start);
    cout << "time taken(program): " << prog_duration.count() << " microseconds." << endl;
}
```

I am using pgi/19.4 on my classes virtual machine and I am compiling and running the code with

```
pgc++ -ta=tesla -Minfo=accel matmul_acc.cpp
srun -p cisc372 --gres=gpu:1 ./a.out
```

and getting the following message

```
srun: error: beowulf: task 0: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am new to openacc and pgi, and I have looked for a fix for the past 3hrs on the internet. If anyone knows what the issue with my code is I would greatly appreciate any advice or fixes. Sorry if there is any similar questions to this one already but I couldn't find any that fit my issue.

Comment: What I'm seeing is that it's core dumping even when built without OpenACC or built with g++ and it's doing so nearly immediately. I think there's something more fundamental happening here, but it's not immediately obvious to me what it is. Do you have a reference version that was working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your segfault is due to your use of stack variables that have grown too large. Reducing their size seems to make the segfault go away for me (try 256), but the real solution would be to make them dynamically allocated. The indexing gets more complicated, but then you can run much larger matrices. There's some other OpenACC problems in the code though that you'll want to address next:

1) The `#pragma acc loop` directives on the initialization loops don't do anything. You need them to either be `#pragma acc parallel loop` or `#pragma kernels loop` before they'll be parallelized. Since your data region is below these loops, you're probably meaning to just delete the loop pragmas altogether.

2) The `#pragma kernels` doesn't do anything either, it needs to be `#pragma acc kernels`. If I do this, then it builds for the GPU.